# Uniform approximation of step function by polynomials in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation, step-function

Let $K_1\subset K_2 \subset \mathbb{C}$ be compact. Let $h(z)$ be a function defined by

\begin{align*}
h(z) = \left\{ \begin{matrix}
1 & \text{if }z\in K_1\\
0 & \qquad\text{ if }z\in K_2\setminus K_1
\end{matrix} \right.
\end{align*}

Can we say $h(z)$ can be approximated uniformly by polynomials of $z$ for arbitrary ? If not, what about the case when $K_1$ and $K_2$ have no interior?

Answer (score 1):

There is the obvious obstruction that, if $K_2$ is connected and $\emptyset\subsetneq K_1\subsetneq K_2$, then $h$ is not continuous on $K_2$, and therefore it cannot be approximated uniformly by continuous functions. Similarly, this is the case as soon as $K_1$ is not union of connected components of $K_2$.